# How can I change the height of a dropdown box in angular?

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to adjust the scroll view hight because it's too long, any solution?

I tried to use css with no success.
As you can see in the image below, the current scroll view is too long.

[image]

Comment: can you share a piece of code ? How to you create your dropdowns ?

Comment: i add a pic with my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use property binding for height.you can change it run time.

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: use ngStyle or [style.height] in html and bind it to the property of class(typescript class)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you will need to use a library to customize your dropdown. In fact this html tag is native and depends on your browser, I recommend [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) to do this :)